# Consuming default export with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I would like to use a small javascript library within a typescript project.  (For the [full example see here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/14790#issuecomment-297092104)).

The javascript library defines the following:

```
"use strict";

exports.__esModule = true;
exports["default"] = functionOfInterest;
function functionOfInterest(val) {    }
module.exports = exports["default"];
```

This has been typed using a `.d.ts` file as:

```
export default function functionOfInterest(val: number): void;
```

In a typescript file I use:

```
import functionOfInterest from "the-package";

functionOfInterest(1);  // invoke it.
```

This is compiled to:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var functionOfInterest_1 = require("the-package");
functionOfInterest_1.default.apply(void 0, 1);
```

This errors with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

My `tsconfig.json` file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "js",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "ts",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

I'm sure there's just a simple configuration error somewhere but I can't figure it out at the moment.

Typescript 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
import functionOfInterest = require("the-package");

(functionOfInterest as any)(1);
```

** **Alternatively** **

You can change the definition file to:

```
declare function functionOfInterest(val: number): void;
export = functionOfInterest;
```

And then consume without the cast to `any`:

```
import functionOfInterest = require("the-package");

functionOfInterest(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import * as _ thePackage from "the-package";

thePackage.functionOfInterest(1);
```

Comment: With Typescript 2.2.2, this errors with:  `[ts] String literal expected. [ts] 'from' expected. any`